# Very serious multiplication bug when subscripts are used

Tags: version-10, algebra

I have found a serious bug in Mathematica 10.0.1.0 on mac os x. See the attached screenshot.
It is applying the square root to the Mpc. I am very shocked by this. Does anyone know how to avoid this bug. I don't want to have to check all my calculations by hand!

To reproduce it you can copy, paste and evaluate:

```
 (CellPrint@#; NotebookLocate["badboxparsing"];     SelectionEvaluateCreateCell[EvaluationNotebook[]]) &@  Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"k", "/",  RowBox[{"(",  RowBox[{"h", " ",  SuperscriptBox[ RowBox[{SuperscriptBox["Mpc",  RowBox[{"-", "1"}]], "(",  SuperscriptBox[RowBox[{ SubsuperscriptBox["\[CapitalOmega]", "m",  RowBox[{"2", "/", "3"}]], "(",  RowBox[{"1", "-", SubscriptBox["\[CapitalOmega]", "m"]}],")"}],RowBox[{"1", "/", "3"}]], ")"}], RowBox[{"1", "/", "2"}]]}], ")"}]}]], "Input",    CellTags -> "badboxparsing"]
```

**Update:** The way the bug arises is if you have the equation in text mode and you then copy and paste into Input mode. See this [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xsj4s458srlj2yc/mathematica_bug.nb?dl=0) for example. Mathematica support have reproduced the bug and have filed a report on it.

[image: screenshot of bug]

Note: The bug shows up only when the subscripts are there.

Comment: Please post code and not images when possible

Comment: I can't reproduce your result on **Windows**

Comment: @belisarius I would like to post code but the bug only works when the subscripts are there and I don't know how to do subscripts in the code. I added a link to the file.

Comment: @RunnyKine please try with linked file.

Comment: @belisarius I confirmed this in version 8 and answered based on what I saw there. I strongly suspect that it's the same in version 10.

Comment: Copy and paste and evaluate and never use subscripts again:                     `(CellPrint@#; NotebookLocate["badboxparsing"]; 
   SelectionEvaluateCreateCell[EvaluationNotebook[]]) &@
 Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"k", "/", 
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"h", " ", 
SuperscriptBox[
RowBox[{SuperscriptBox["Mpc", 
RowBox[{"-", "1"}]], "(", 
SuperscriptBox[RowBox[{
SubsuperscriptBox["\[CapitalOmega]", "m", 
RowBox[{"2", "/", "3"}]], "(", 
RowBox[{"1", "-", SubscriptBox["\[CapitalOmega]", "m"]}],")"}],RowBox[{"1", "/", "3"}]], ")"}], RowBox[{"1", "/", "2"}]]}], ")"}]}]], "Input", 
  CellTags -> "badboxparsing"]`

Comment: @RolfMertig Thanks, that reproduces the error.  I want mathematica to be like a real calculation where I can use subscripts. I really think they need to make the program robust to subscripts otherwise it loses a lot of its attraction.

Comment: @physicsphile Subscripts aren't robust enough for non-experts and usually you'll only get headaches from them. Try to stay away from subs/supers or at least search this site with related keywords to know what to expect.

Comment: @belisarius if someone has found a similar error, please let me have a link to that post.

Comment: @physicsphile If you have purchased Mathematica I really think you should see if you can return it. The band gap between your expectations and their delivery is going to be too great and cause you far too much aggravation.

Comment: @Bill I find mathematica very useful but I do not think I am in any way being unreasonable in pointing out this bug. This is a major bug. Maybe for experts who never use subscripts its Ok. But for your average user this really does need to be fixed in my opinion.

Comment: I'm not as negative about subscripts as others here but you really need to be using `Symbolize` for effective error free subscripts (...or use Mathcad where it is seamless).

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch symbolize doesn't help with this example unfortunately.

Comment: @physicsphile it works fine for me

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I wonder what you are doing differently to me. My notebook is at: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xsj4s458srlj2yc/mathematica_bug.nb?dl=0

Comment: @physicsphile ok this seems to be a bug with V10. Your notebook evaluated fine for me using V9 and tried with V10 and got the bug. I'm using OS X 10.9.5. Maybe we can get a few others to try both 9 and 10 and confirm bug in V10.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I get the bug both in Mma 10 and Mma 9.0.1.0. I am also using mac os x 10.9.5.

Comment: As I said I had no issues with 9.0.1 with the notebook you linked.

Comment: OK, I'm not sure why if we are using the same system and same file I am still getting the problem while you are not.

Comment: I reproduced the problem as instructed in the updated question. But when I evaluated the pasted the expression Mathematica warned me about the dangers of pasting from TraditionalForm. Didn't you get this warning?

Comment: Thanks, I see I do get a warning message in the console when I paste the expression from text to input mode: "There is a problem with the position of the text insertion point. The insertion point might not be where you intended." At least that is something I can watch out for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's clear from the box form of the expression in the notebook you linked that there is a misplaced `RowBox` wrapping the `Mpc` together with the right parenthesis that immediately *precedes* the `^(1/2)` power. This is then incorrectly interpreted as `Mpc` being inside the square root. I have no idea how this `RowBox` got there, but when I simply highlight this parenthesis in `)^(1/2)` (the one on the left) and re-type it, the expression is fixed.

It is indeed disconcerting that a malformed box form like this cannot be visually recognized as containing an error, because it prints correctly. Moreover, in this case the interpretation of the input seems to give precedence to the `RowBox` grouping, over the grouping of terms by matching parentheses. That cannot be right. I would file a bug report showing the following box forms hidden in your input:

```
DisplayForm[RowBox[{"k", "/", 
     RowBox[{"(", 
        RowBox[{"h", " ", 
           SuperscriptBox[
             RowBox[{
                SuperscriptBox["Mpc", 
                  RowBox[{"-", "1"}]], "(", 
                SuperscriptBox[
                  RowBox[{
                     SubsuperscriptBox["Ω", "m", 
                       RowBox[{"2", "/", "3"}]], "(", 
                     RowBox[{"1", "-", 
                        SubscriptBox["Ω", "m"]}], ")"}], 
                  RowBox[{"1", "/", "3"}]], ")"}], 
             RowBox[{"1", "/", "2"}]]}], ")"}]}]]
```

The offending `RowBox` is on line 5. If you execute this command and copy the output into an input cell, you reproducibly get the incorrect result mentioned in the question.

i would be curious how you managed to type in this input in the first place. Was it generated by some other low-level operation, perhaps?

Comment: Thank you Jens.I have already written to support about this and will point them to your post when they reply. By the way I just entered that expression by hand as far as I remember. The only defense I can think of is always to put in an explicit * whenever I have a symbol next to brackets. Hopefully that works, I am really disappointed about this.

Comment: @Jens by editing in the frontend one can get weird things. Parsing then sometimes results in true errors. The only way out is to not use subscripts (which I usually do since a long time).

Comment: On second thoughts, its possible I copied and pasted part of the expression from another part of the notebook as I don't seem to get the bug when I enter the expression completely by hand. I still think it is a very serious bug which I hope they fix soon.

Comment: @RolfMertig That's indeed good advice. Subscripts are in general full of pitfalls, especially for people who don't know anything about `DownValues`... But this seems to be a good test case showing a shortcoming of the parser that looks fixable.

Comment: @Jens I have updated the post with how to get the bug by copying and pasting a text expression.

Comment: @physicsphile Good to know they acknowledged the bug.